# How can I flag duplicates in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I would like to know a method for flagging values in an array, removing the duplicates and combining some of the data **in Java**.

I am keeping a record of geo locations using lat, long and description this is encoded in a JSON array as follows:

```
[{"lon": 0.001, "lat": 0.001, "desc": test}, {"lon": 0.001, "lat": 0.001, "desc": test2}]
```

I would like to be able to remove the duplicate geo locations while keeping the "desc" part of the array, e.g.

```
[{"lon": 0.001, "lat": 0.001, "desc": test, test2}]
```

**Edit**:
This is what I am currently doing:

```
//Store locPoints from server in JSONArray
JSONArray jPointsArray = new JSONArray(serverData); 
List<JSONObject> jObjects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
List<JSONObject> seenObjects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

 for(int i = 0; i < jPointsArray.length(); ++i)
{
 jObjects.add(jPointsArray.getJSONObject(i));
}        
 for (JSONObject obj : jObjects) 
                {
                    //This always returns true
                    if (!seenObjects.contains(obj))// && !seenObjects.contains(obj.get("lon")))
                    {

                        Log.i("Sucess", "Huzzah!");
                        seenObjects.add(obj);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                         //merge the 'desc' field in 'obj' with the 'desc' field in
                         JSONObject original = (JSONObject)seenObjects.get(seenObjects.indexOf(obj));
                         JSONObject update = obj;
                         original.put("desc", original.get("desc") + ", " + update.get("desc"));
                         seenObjects.get(seenObjects.indexOf(obj)).get("desc"));

                    }
                }
```

Comment: So what is your question?  It looks like your problem is already solved, no?

Comment: @dmcnelis I have been trying to sort that into a workable example but cant get my head round it so was hoping I could get a better example, e.g. in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
//assuming that the array you are filtering is called 'myArray'
List<Object> seenObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (Object obj : myArray) {
    if (! seenObjects.contains(obj)) {
        seenObjects.add(obj);
    }
    else {
        //merge the 'desc' field in 'obj' with the 'desc' field in
        //'seenObjects.get(seenObjects.indexOf(obj))'
    }
}
```

Note that this will only work if the objects you are comparing have implementations of `equals()` and `hashCode()` that do what you want (in your case, they should only take into consideration the 'lat' and 'lon' fields).

Update:

Here is some complete example code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

public class JsonMergeTest {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> myArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
        myArray.add(MyJsonObject.parse("{\"lon\": 0.001, \"lat\": 0.001, \"desc\": \"test\"}"));
        myArray.add(MyJsonObject.parse("{\"lon\": 0.001, \"lat\": 0.001, \"desc\": \"test2\"}"));

        List seenObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for (Object obj : myArray) {
            if (! seenObjects.contains(obj)) {
                seenObjects.add(obj);
            }
            else {
                //merge the 'desc' field in 'obj' with the 'desc' field in the list
                MyJsonObject original = (MyJsonObject)seenObjects.get(seenObjects.indexOf(obj));
                MyJsonObject update = (MyJsonObject)obj;
                original.put("desc", original.get("desc") + ", " + update.get("desc"));
            }
        }

        for (MyJsonObject obj : (List<MyJsonObject>)seenObjects) {
            System.out.println(obj.toJSONString());
        }
    }

    private static class MyJsonObject extends JSONObject  {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null || ! (obj instanceof MyJsonObject) || ! this.containsKey("lat") || ! this.containsKey("lon")) {
                return super.equals(obj);
            }
            MyJsonObject jsonObj = (MyJsonObject)obj;
            return this.get("lat").equals(jsonObj.get("lat")) && this.get("lon").equals(jsonObj.get("lon"));
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            if (! this.containsKey("lat") || ! this.containsKey("lon")) {
                return super.hashCode();
            }
            return this.get("lat").hashCode() ^ this.get("lon").hashCode();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static Object parse(String json) {
            Object parsedJson = JSONValue.parse(json);
            if (! (parsedJson instanceof JSONObject)) {
                return parsedJson;
            }

            MyJsonObject result = new MyJsonObject();
            result.putAll((JSONObject)parsedJson);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @aroth this looks to be what I need, how do I use seenObject.get(obj) since it is a collection?

Comment: You're right, I updated the example to use a List instead of a Set, which makes it easier to get the original object out for the merge operation.

Comment: @aroth at the moment this isn't working for me I am using JSONObjects and using this if statement  

if (!seenObjects.contains(obj.get("lat")) && !seenObjects.contains(obj.get("lon")))

but it always returns true.

Comment: Why are you using `(!seenObjects.contains(obj.get("lat")) && !seenObjects.contains(obj.get("lon")))`?  That will not work unless you also change `seenObjects.add(obj);` to `seenObjects.add(obj.get("lat")); seenObjects.add(obj.get("lon"));`.  And even that will most likely not work without several other changes to the code.

Comment: @aroth I have changed the question to reflect what I am currently doing, if you could take a look that would be great.

Comment: It looks like what you are doing is mostly correct, except that you are using the default JSONObject implementation.  The problem there is that the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the default implementation are not going to do what you want.  You need to create a custom JSONObject subclass, similar to the `MyJsonObject` class in my sample code, which overrides the default implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: @aroth Ok, one more thing (must be sick of this huh) the this.containsKey() method is implemented how?

Comment: Well the example code uses the [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) API, in which JSONObject inherits `containsKey()` from HashMap.  It looks like your code is using the json.org API, which is less friendly.  Perhaps you could do `try { return this.get(key) != null; } catch (JSONException e) { return false; }`

Comment: @aroth I have added the Library you mentioned, the final problem that I am having (I think) is that the data I am comparing is one long JSON encoded string, and I need to separate each value into another add call for the list much like in your code, you know a method of getting a set of values e.g. {[lat = 0.1, lon = 0.1, desc = test]}

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). And follow the steps:

**1.** Define an equivalent POJO in Java, to map the JSON String

```
public class Location implements Comparable<Location> {
    public String lon;
    public String lat;
    public String desc;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<lon: " + lon +", lat: "+ lat +", desc: " + desc +">";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((Location)obj).lon.equals(lon) && ((Location)obj).lat.equals(lat); 
    }

    public int compareTo(Location obj) {
        return ((Location)obj).lon.compareTo(lon) + ((Location)obj).lat.compareTo(lat);
    }


}
```

**2.** Write the code that merges similar location. OK, it's Sunday, lets do it :)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
      //Some test data
    String s = "[" +
            " {\"lon\": 0.001, \"lat\": 0.001, \"desc\": \"test\"}," +
            " {\"lon\": 0.002, \"lat\": 0.001, \"desc\": \"test3\"}," +
            " {\"lon\": 0.002, \"lat\": 0.005, \"desc\": \"test4\"}," +
            " {\"lon\": 0.002, \"lat\": 0.001, \"desc\": \"test5\"}," +
            " {\"lon\": 0.001, \"lat\": 0.001, \"desc\": \"test2\"}]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Location[] al = gson.fromJson(s, Location[].class);
    List<Location> tl = Arrays.asList(al);

     //lets sort so that similar locations are grouped
    Collections.sort(tl);
    List<Location> fl = new ArrayList<Location>();
    Location current = null;

     //merge!
    for(Iterator<Location> it = tl.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        current = current==null?it.next():current;
        Location ltmp = null;
        while(it.hasNext() && (ltmp = it.next()).equals(current))
            current.desc = current.desc + "," + ltmp.desc;
        fl.add(current);
        current = ltmp;
    }

       //convert back to JSON?
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(fl));

}
```

**3.** output

```
[{"lon":"0.002","lat":"0.005","desc":"test4"},
{"lon":"0.002","lat":"0.001","desc":"test3,test5"},
{"lon":"0.001","lat":"0.001","desc":"test,test2"}]
```